# Makefiles: How do they determine build targets?

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

I'm running into interesting behavior in an inherited makefile that I'm trying to expand for my current project.

```
LIBS := lib/precompiled1.a lib/precompiled2.a lib/mylib1.a lib/mylib2.a

mylib1-src := (source directory)
mylib1-obj := $(patsubst $(mylib1-src)/%.c, obj/LIB1/%.o, $(wildcard $(mylib1-src)/*.c))

mylib2-src := (source directory)
mylib2-obj := $(patsubst $(mylib2-src)/%.cpp, obj/LIB2/%.o, $(wildcard $(mylib2-src)/*.cpp))

default: all

lib/mylib1.a: $(mylib1-obj)
    ar -r $@ $^

lib/mylib2.a: $(mylib2-obj)
    ar -r $@ $^

all: exe/my_out

exe/my_out: $(my_out-obj)
    g++ $^ $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(LIBS) $(MY_FLAGS)
```

When I run make, I run into an error where it can't link against lib/mylib1.a, and it breaks. Cool, I just need to make sure that the .a target is being built. Messing naively around with the makefile like so:

```
lib/mylib1.a: $(mylib1-obj)
    ar -r $@ $^

lib/mylib2.a: $(mylib2-obj)
    ar -r $@ $^

default: all
```

This now compiles mylib1.a just fine, but compiles neither mylib2.a or 'all'.

This is where I got stuck. If I do the following:

```
default: all

lib/mylib1.a: $(mylib1-obj)
    ar -r $@ $^

lib/mylib2.a: $(mylib2-obj)
    ar -r $@ $^

all: lib/mylib1.a exe/my_out
```

then the compiler complains about lib/mylib1.a not being an executable. Which it isn't, great, but leaves me stuck in a weird situation. I can compile the .a files individually. I can link them against the executable. I can't do all of those things at once, only by messing around with the makefile, which somewhat defeats the point.

My question is, why does changing the order of default change what gets built? How can I get all of the .a files to build and link against the main executable without manually messing with the makefile each time? I'm fairly new to makefiles in general, and I'm not sure why this behavior is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the targets in a makefile doesn't matter, with one exception: the first one is the default goal, i.e. the one worked on when you call `make` without a goal. This behavior can be changed in GNU make with `.DEFAULT_GOAL := ...`

#### Dependency order

What does matter in a serial build (`make -j1`) is the order of dependencies in a target definition, e.g.

```
T: A B C
```

or

```
T: A B
T: C
    rule
```

In a serial build `make` will first fulfill "A", then "B", then "C". If "C" has a missing dependency that is fulfilled while "A" is being built then the build will succeed. Change the makefile to

```
T: C A B
```

... and the serial build will start to fail.

In a parallel build (`make -jN`) the dependency order doesn't matter, because `make` will try to build "A", "B" and "C" in parallel, if it is allowed to.

#### Incomplete dependencies

If a mandatory dependency "D" isn't listed for a target "T", then `make` will allow building of target "T" once the listed dependencies are fulfilled. But it will not wait for "D" to be completed. The build success therefore depends on undefined behavior, either

1. "D" did already exist before the build started and isn't touched by the current build, or
2. target "D" is fulfilled before target "T" is started.

Worst case scenario for a parallel build: if the rule for "T" does not fail while reading "D" and "D" is being written at the same time, then you end up with a successful build, but invalid build artifacts.

The usual indicators for incomplete dependencies are

- build starts to (randomly) fail when switching from serial to parallel,
- build starts to randomly fail when moving to another build machine, or
- build artifacts from a successful build with strange test failures.

#### Solution

Always specify full dependencies for all targets. In your case that would at least be:

```makefile
# Add internal dependencies included in $(LIBS)
exe/my_out: $(my_out-obj) $(filter lib/%.a, $(LIBS))
    g++ $^ $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(LIBS) $(MY_FLAGS)
```

Comment: Thanks! This clears up a lot of questions that the other answers didn't for me, and helps me understand the makefile process a lot more. If you could move the section "The order of the targets in a makefile doesn't matter, with one exception: the first one is the default target, i.e. the one worked on when you call make without a target" to the start of the post to make it easier to find for anyone with similar problems, I'd be happy to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Done. I agree it does improve the answer.

Comment: @Garrett if this answered the question for you, you should consider marking this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

The default target is the first target in the Makefile, The target named 'default' has no special significance.

For recent versions of Make, the default target can be specified explicitly like this:

DEFAULT_GOAL := all

The libraries should be added as prerequisites for the executable, rather than to the all target, e.g:

```
exe/my_out: $(my_out-obj) lib/mylib1.a lib/mylib2.a
    g++ $^ $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(LIBS) $(MY_FLAGS)

lib/mylib1.a: $(mylib1-obj)
    ar -r $@ $^

lib/mylib2.a: $(mylib2-obj)
    ar -r $@ $^
```

Comment: This is helpful! However, it doesn't help with the second half of my question. The .a files are built when they're the default target, but attempting to add them to target 'all' causes them to be either ignored or causes make to attempt to execute them. Any guidance on that?

Answer (score 0):

As Andy suggests force the default rule to be `all:` by doing this (usually near the top of the makefile):

`.DEFAULT_GOAL = all`

Then define all as:

```
LIB_DEPS = lib/mylib1.a lib/mylib2.a
all: exe/my_out $(LIB_DEPS)

# Also to ensure that the libs are built first (for example with parallel builds):
exe/my_out: $(my_out-obj) $(LIB_DEPS)
    ... recipe here...
```

This way if you do make or make -j your build order is guaranteed.

**Note** I did not see a rule for `$(my_out-obj)` - did you miss that or is it just not printed?

Comment: Just not printed, as it wasn't relevant to the question at hand and difficult to type out. (Machine that the makefile is on doesn't have internet access.)

Comment: @Garrett ok fair enough - just needed to check that : )